# Converting http service to https in Biztalk Dynamic Solicit Request Response port

Tags: wcf, http, https, biztalk

I come across a very strange position, I was working on a project in BizTalk, initially I had to consume WCF services deployed on **http**. Now after a lot of work done. They just updated their bindings to **https**. Now what is option for me. how I change my orchestration. When I try toupdate service send port (**http to https**). I receive following error message on Biztalk.

[image]

Please guide me how to cater with this issue.

Regards,

Comment: You cannot just change the url. Did you update the bindings in your send port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'll need to use another port type, like WCF-Custom.

Comment: This is not correct. You can use WCF-BasicHttp ports to connect to SSL-secured services.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `Security mode` property in the `Security` tab to be `Transport` (or `TransportWithMessageCredential`) if you want to use `https`.